# How to render array of objects in javascript react if its undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to check for the empty array in react JavaScript. But when I am using the question mark for checking that is it undefined or not then the react and is crashing.

I am using something like this:

```
const [verlist, setverlist] = useState([]);
```

In the `useEffect` hook I'm using `setverlist(response.versions.version)`. Here `versions` is object. And in it `version` is an array of objects.

But when I get versions as empty object `{}`, my react app crashes because in console I'm getting undefined.

I'm rendering like this:

`{[...verlist].reverse().map((value, id) => {})}`

How do I fix this ?

Comment: is `verlist` an array or object? because you said: 'But when I get versions as empty object `{}`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a check in front of your code.

`verlist && verlist.length > 0 && [...verlist].reverse().map((value, id) => {})`

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Change

from : `[...verlist].reverse().map((value, id) => {})`

to: `verlist.length > 0 && [...verlist].reverse().map((value, id) => {})`

Comment: The app is again crashing

Comment: Can u add the whole page?

Answer (score 0):

If `verlist` is an array and can be undefined, try:

```
verlist && verlist.length && [...verlist].reverse().map((value, id) => {})
```